# angularjs, how to pass parent scope isolated variable to a directive, and watch the variable value

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to connect a parent controller variable `searchText` to a directive.
I would actually like to do it in such a way that my template can also connect to the same variable. It's a simple text field.

Initially I thought I would need to create a watch, and set the variable manually, but it turns out the linking works anyway.

I am battling to understand why the watch executes once, and never again.

I have a working **[codepen here](http://codepen.io/jimmymain/pen/EKKmKO)**, where the watch is logged to the console.

html

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <div class="container">
      <span>TEXT :: {{searchText.searchText}}</span>          
      <div data-locate="locate" search="searchText">SB:{{searchTextBox}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

controller.

```
export class TestController {
    static $inject = ["$scope", "$timeout", "$log"];
    constructor($scope: any, $timeout: any, public $log: any) {
        $scope.searchText = { searchText: 'initial' };
        $timeout(() => $scope.searchText.searchText = 'new value....');
    }
}
```

directive

```
export class Locate {
    public restrict: string = "A";
    public template: string = "<input class='form-control' name='SearchText' type='text' ng-model='searchTextBox.searchText' />";
    public scope: any =
    {
        search: "=",
    }
    constructor(public $log: any) {            
    }
    public link: Function = ($scope: any, element: any) => {                       $scope.searchTextBox = 'a';
        // this code links the searchTextBox to the scope.
        $scope.searchTextBox = $scope.search;
        this.$log.log($scope.search);

         $scope.$watch('search', (o, n) => {

            // this watch only get's called once, and never again.

            this.$log.log(`watch called ${JSON.stringify(o)} :: ${JSON.stringify(n)}`);
            if (n) {
                this.$log.log(`watch updating ${JSON.stringify(n)}`);                    

                // it turns out the below code is not necessary, but
                // it only gets' called once, even when the value changes.
                $scope.searchTextBox = n;
            }
        });
    }          
    static factory(): any {
        const directive = ($log: any) => new Locate($log);
        directive.$inject = ['$log'];
        return directive;
    }    
}
Test.testApp.directive('locate', Locate.factory());
Test.testApp.controller('TestController', TestController);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The watch needs to include an additional boolean `true` value on the watch to perform a deep comparison.

```
     $scope.$watch('search', (o, n) => {

        // this watch only get's called once, and never again.

        this.$log.log(`watch called ${JSON.stringify(o)} :: ${JSON.stringify(n)}`);
        if (n) {
            this.$log.log(`watch updating ${JSON.stringify(n)}`);                    

            // it turns out the below code is not necessary, but
            // it only gets' called once, even when the value changes.
            $scope.searchTextBox = n;
        }
    }, true); // the true is necessary
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use controllerAs you need to specify it in your html.

try:

```
<body ng-controller="AController as td">
    <div locate searchText="td.searchText">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: if I take the 'as' out, put all the variables on the scope, it still doesn't work. in the directive, the link function has `searchText` undefined, but the parent scope has 'init' the value is not being passed down.

Comment: I am going to edit the question, I am closer now to the heart of the problem.